# Разделить маршруты GET и HEAD в symfony

Tags: php, symfony

В моем приложении необходимо реализовать различную логику для `GET` и `HEAD` запросов. По `HEAD` внешняя система должна получить 200 или 404 в зависимости от существования документа. Если документ существует, то внешняя система перенаправляет пользователя по тому же адресу, где уже открывается полноценная страница с авторизацией и т.д.

Но, как оказалось, в `symfony` запросы `HEAD` заменяются на `GET` [Unacessible routes in prod because HEAD request becomes GET #21074](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21074)

Т.е. при запросе `HEAD` в контроллере:

```
class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/document/{id}", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getAction(string $id): Response
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/document/{id}", methods={"HEAD"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function headAction(string $id): Response
    {
        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

выполнится getAction. Можно ли изменить такое поведение в конфигурации? Иначе в голову ничего не приходит кроме проверки `REQUEST_METHOD`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cabinet/{id}", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @param string $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAction(string $id, Request $request): Response
{
    if($request->server->getAlpha('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'HEAD') {
        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко, то нельзя разделить.

Symfony исходят из [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2)

> Метод HEAD **идентичен** GET за исключением того, что сервер НЕ
> ОТПРАВЛЯЕТ **тело сообщения** в ответе.
>
> HEAD может повлиять на ранее кэшированные GET-ответы [RFC7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3.5) (тут
> описан механизм Freshening Responses для HEAD).

---

Этот вопрос поднимался несколько раз ([раз](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20893), [два](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/20998), [три](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21074), [четыре](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22028)) и так и [заглох](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28743) как я понял.

Думаю, можно попробовать вытащить метод из `$this->context->getMethod()`

Ну и соответсвенно изменить контроллер

```
 /**
 * @Route("/cabinet/{id}", methods={"GET", "HEAD"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @param string $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAction(string $id, Request $request): Response
{
    if($this->context->getMethod() === 'HEAD') {
        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```